# installing modules when using perlbrew

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, perl-module, perlbrew

I am trying to use perlbrew to run a set of perl scripts. When I try installing dependencies for these perl scripts, they are installed into my system's perl version (5.18.X) and not the version I want to use (5.10.1). I have tried several suggestions from other threads on stackoverflow, but to no avail.

Here's an example of what happens. I'll do the following:

> perlbrew use perl-5.10.1
>
> perl -v (returns with perl-5.10.1)
>
> cpanm Parallel::ForkManager (returns Paralell::ForkManager is installed)

When I run my script using under perlbrew I get the following:

> perl PERLSCRIPT.pl
>
> Can't locate Parallel/ForkManager.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/qwerty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/qwerty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1 /home/qwerty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/qwerty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1

Any help is appreciated. If any other information is needed, please let me know.

System OS: Ubuntu 64-bit run through VMware (host is Windows 8.1 pro);

Edit: It seems that doing `perlbrew exec cpanm perl::module` works. However, If anyone has other suggestions, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: Did you install `cpanm` with `perlbrew install-cpanm`? What does `which cpanm` show?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thanks for the quick response. Doing `perlbrew install-cpanm` returns `cpanm is installed to  /home/qwerty/perl5/perlbrewbin/cpanm`.  When I do `which cpanm` I get `/home/qwerty/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
perlbrew switch perl-5.10.1
```

instead of

```
perlbrew use perl-5.10.1
```

The "use" command only sets the perl for the current shell. Maybe you switched shells in between?

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, but still relevant! (this bit me in 2023).

Answer: Be sure `PERL5LIB` is not set.

In my case, I previously (before installing perlbrew) had the usual CPAN local::lib setup and set PERL5LIB=$HOME/lib/perl5/lib/perl5 in my .profile which made perl look there before it's "system" locations (perlbrew compiles Perl with a special Config which replaces /usr/local with a version-specific subdir, and that's where perlbrew's cpanm installs stuff).